# programs' systray icon remains after program stops running in some cases

Tags: vb.net

I have a (vb.net) program which creates a systray icon when it is launched.

When it exits normally the systray icon is removed correctly.

However, in some cases, for example when the program is 'end tasked' using MS task manager the program's systray icon remains.

This presents the very unfortunate illusion that the program is still running when it is not.

However, in these situations, once the user moves their mouse over the program's systray icon the program's systray icon disappears.

Is there anyway to ensure the systray icon is removed in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application is killed ("end tasked"), you don't get a chance to tidy up first. Your app is simply removed from memory, and there's no warning (or any way to prevent it). It's like having a hole in the ground suddenly appear beneath your feet - you don't get a chance to call home to say goodbye to your spouse or significant other first. You're just gone.)

For the other problems (the occasional "phantom icon" that remains after your app is closed properly), there is a solution. I'm not sure how it's normally resolved using .NET, but with plain old WinAPI programming you can use [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send your window a `WM_NULL` message when your application exits to cause the system tray to refresh its icons, which causes the phantom icon to disappear.

I've never done this in .NET, but a quick check of [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/PostMessage.html) shows something like this should work (untested, but it compiles and executes in VB.NET via VS Express 2012 - I clearly didn't write an actual systray app to test whether it works or not, because causing the "phantom icon" to appear intentionally is difficult):

```
Private Declare Function PostMessage _
    Lib "coredll.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal Msg As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As Integer, _
    ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, _
                             e As FormClosedEventArgs) _
                             Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Const WM_NULL As Integer = &H0
    PostMessage(Me.Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Note that it's **extremely important** to use [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and not [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose. The first simply places the message in the message queue and returns, while the second waits for a response (and your app won't be there to send one, as it's already in the process of closing).

Note #2: You may need to do this in your `Form1_FormClosing` handler instead of `FormClosed`; as I said, I don't have a systray application to use to test the timing of the proper place to use for posting the message.

Comment: Thank you.  However, when I end task my program neither the formclosed or the formclosing events are firing.  I also tried adding this in under the HandleDestroyed, MyApplication_Shutdown and MyApplication_UnhandledException events, but they don't fire either when the program is 'end tasked'.

Comment: Nothing fires when the "program is end tasked". That's an abnormal forced shutdown, and you aren't given a chance to clean up. There's absolutely nothing you can do in that event - Windows is simply killing your process. (It's like someone sneaking up behind you, putting a gun against your head, and pulling the trigger. You don't get a chance to call your spouse or significant other and say goodbye.) The code I posted solves the problem of the "ghost icon" that sometimes remains when a system tray application is closed. A "killed task" is simply dead, and can't tidy up first.

Comment: ok thank you - but as far as I know I am not having a problem when the program ends normally.  Also you'd think that if Windows was going to assassinate a process it would at least try and hide the body afterwards :-)

Comment: :-) It does, as soon as it notices it needs to (that's why moving the mouse over the system tray makes it disappear). All it knows when you've been "end tasked" is that the user has said "Stop this program now. Yes, I'm sure that's what I want done!". Oswald (or whoever) didn't attempt to hide JFK's body after the deed was done. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer (see the new first paragraph), with a somewhat less violent example of what's happening to your application when an "end task" is done. :-)